# What is the point of applying nio relativize for two totally different /unrelated absolute paths?

Tags: java, nio

I understand the following - it makes sense to me:

```
    Path path3 = Paths.get("/partA/partB");
    Path path4 = Paths.get("/partA/partC");
   
    System.out.println(path3.relativize(path4));
    System.out.println(path4.relativize(path3));
```

it prints

> ../partC
>
> ../partB

I understand that both partB and partC have a common parent folder called partA. Therefore these two paths can logically be relativized and ../ in printed result above refers to this common parent folder.

BUT when I do the same with two totally unrelated absolute paths as follows:

```
    path3 = Paths.get("/xyz");
    path4 = Paths.get("/folder/abc");
    
    System.out.println("path3 is absolute - "+path3.isAbsolute()); 
    System.out.println("path4 is absolute - "+path4.isAbsolute()); 

    Path path3a = path3.relativize(path4);
    System.out.println(path3a);
    Path path4a = path4.relativize(path3);
    System.out.println(path4a);
```

I get the following result:

> path3 is absolute - true
>
> path4 is absolute - true
>
> ../folder/abc
>
> ../../xyz

This does NOT make sense to me. I thought two unrelated absolute paths can be relativized assuming they represent paths of two different computers in a local network for example.

If this understanding is correct then why in first case I get ../  ( one folder upper level ) but in other case I get ../../ (two folders upper ) - if they are both absolute folders in a network should not they have a common parent at network level ? That is, should not the following be the result ? :

> ../folder/abc
>
> ../xyz

If my understanding is incorrect what is the logic behind the second relativize (with unrelated absolute paths) ) ? What is the application of this all in real life case ? When it can be useful ?

And when I convert this to absolute path as follows I get lost even more :

```
    Path path3b = path3a.toAbsolutePath();
    Path path4b = path4a.toAbsolutePath();
    Path path3c = path3b.normalize();
    Path path4c = path4b.normalize();
    System.out.println("path3a - "+path3a+" \npath4a - "+path4a);
    System.out.println("path3b - "+path3b+" \npath4b - "+path4b);
    System.out.println("path3c - "+path3c+" \npath4c - "+path4c);
```

it prints:

> path3a - ../folder/abc
>
> path4a - ../../xyz
>
> path3b - /Users/myMac/NetBeansProjects/OCP/../folder/abc
>
> path4b - /Users/myMac/NetBeansProjects/OCP/../../xyz
>
> path3c - /Users/myMac/NetBeansProjects/folder/abc
>
> path4c - /Users/myMac/xyz

I am totally lost because how come a relativized path on two absolute paths get added to current path in my computer - should not it be converted back to original absolute paths? What I am missing in understanding the pure logic and application of this all  ?

( I understand how code works, I do not understand logic behind and application in real life case when two unrelated paths are relativized )

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There is no point whatsoever. It doesn't make sense to even try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start at `/folder/abc` and you want to get to `/xyz` you must go up two levels and then descend one. Going up two levels means `../..` and descending one means `xyz`. Together that's `../../xyz`.

Here's what happens when you *resolve* the relative path `../../xyz` with the starting path of `/folder/abc`.

```
/folder/abc + ..  == /folder/abc/.. == /folder
/folder     + ..  == /folder/..     == /
/           + xyz == /xyz
```

To compute the relative path from some path A to an unrelated path B, you must first get to the top level by adding together as many `..`'s as there are directories in A. That gets you to `/`. Then concatenate B.

Comment: thank you for your response. I almost got there. Can you please edit your response to add few comments on the very last code and its output in my question ?  I guess converting it toAbsolutePath() is pointless. However, I would like to get few more expert views on it (in addition to @EJP 's comment above. Then it would be more likely that I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, explanation provided by @JohnKugelman clarifies it  (I accepted this explanation. At the moment of posting this I have 11 reputation points while for voting I need 15 rep. points. Therefore I can not up-vote your answer now. Hope to do it a little later).

Basically, main reason for my misunderstanding was assumption that relativize works in relation to the top level folder in the path - it was not totally illogical because once top level folders in two paths are relativized (map between top level folders of both paths is known) then roadmap from any folder in path one to any folder in path two can be determined. But this understanding was incorrect.

Now I got that to understand relativize properly one needs to bear in mind two points:

1) it turns out that relativize works in relation to the bottom level of the path (not top level folder as I thought, so in case of /folder/abc Java constructs relative path in relation to abc);

2) as stated in fmbesteiro’s answer below, it works as FROM.relativize(TO);

Therefore when I do this:

```
path3 = Paths.get("/xyz");
path4 = Paths.get("/folder/abc");        
System.out.println(path3.relativize(path4));
System.out.println(path4.relativize(path3));
```

and get this:

> ../folder/abc
>
> ../../xyz

in first case (from path3 to path4) as John Kugelman wrote, I have to go up one level and go down two levels to folder first and then to abc. In second case (from path4 to path3) I have to go up two level and then down one level to xyz.

Re converting relativized absolute paths toAbsolutePath() - I understand that it is pointless and meaningless as @EJP mentioned in comment above (if you are working with absolute paths). Since you already work with absolute paths you already know it and why would you use toAbsolutePath() then - I tried it because I was just experimenting with it and expected to get absolute path I used to relativize. But if I get something else it is not a problem since I already know the absolute path.

I also decided to share some code I used to understand relativize and normalize - I hope it will help someone.

```
// prepared for Mac, needs to be changed for Windows 

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class nio2test {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    System.out.println(Paths.get("/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/./dddd").normalize());
    //   /aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd

    System.out.println(Paths.get("/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/../dddd").normalize());
    //   /aaaa/bbbb/dddd

    // note one dot
    System.out.println(Paths.get("/aaaa/./bbbb/cccc/../dddd").normalize());
    //   /aaaa/bbbb/dddd

    System.out.println(Paths.get("/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/../../dddd").normalize());
    //   /aaaa/dddd
    // and so on

     // Note the comma within get - operating system-dependent path.separator is automatically inserted between elements
    System.out.println(Paths.get("/aaaa/.././bbbb","../cccc").normalize());
    //    /cccc


    System.out.println();
    Path currentPath4Java = Paths.get(".");
    System.out.println("currentPath4Java              - "+currentPath4Java);
    System.out.println("currentPath4Java ( relative ) - "+currentPath4Java.toAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("currentPath4Java (normalised) - "+currentPath4Java.toAbsolutePath().normalize());

    System.out.println("this is the location in relation to which Java constructs all relative paths");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using relativize you are infact trying to find out which is the relative path from the Path object which you are using the method to the path you are sending as a parameter. Basically:

```
from.relativize(to)
```

If from is `/a/b/c` and to is `/a/d/e` then the relative path from `/a/b/c` to `/a/d/e` is `../../d/e`

So in your case, going from `/xyz` to `/folder/abc` would require it to be `../folder/abc` and going the other way around from `/folder/abc` to `/xyz` would require the relative path to be `../../xyz`.

Regarding normalize method, think about the `..` as if they were the previous folder accessed, so, for each `..` used you have to go one folder back.